# Azure devops - failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token

Tags: docker, azure-devops, dockerhub

Docker build step fails with the following error in Azure Devops.

```
#2 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#2 sha256:176d02fbc8c3c2358108b09ec3e6a7221f505c8f4f7f2a5a715ffe09208231b7
#2 transferring dockerfile: 467B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#4 [auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io
#4 sha256:7c5e7c450f51d70b458788f7081e98a97950451060bdf1472fae68652c4bc51b
#4 DONE 0.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20.2.0
#3 sha256:a2eba8b22571ff865cefbc1e2bac3b19c9d8b540ee420d6be79459346683549b
#3 ERROR: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fnode%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:20.2.0:
------
node:20.2.0: failed to authorize: failed to fetch oauth token: Get https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fnode%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

Here is my yaml

```yaml
    steps:
    - task: DockerInstaller@0
      displayName: Docker Installer
      inputs:
        dockerVersion: 20.10.6
        releaseType: stable
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Login to Docker Hub
      inputs:
       command: login
       containerRegistry: exhut-blogs-web-service-conn
    - script: |
        docker build . \
        --build-arg REACT_APP_FNX_CLIENT_ID=$FNX_CLIENT_ID  \
        --build-arg REACT_APP_FNX_JWT_AUDIENCE=$FNX_JWT_AUDIENCE  \
        --build-arg REACT_APP_EXHUT_BLOGS_BE_URL=**********  \
        --build-arg REACT_APP_EXHUT_BE_URL=**********  \
        -t $(imageName):prod
      displayName: Build image - prod
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Push image - prod
      inputs:
        repository: $(imageName)
        command: push
        tags: prod
```

Deleted and recreated my service connection. It is setup to authenticate with docker hub on my private account.

Comment: Which agent pool are your `steps` running on? Also how are you authenticating with docker hub in your service connection?